# Remove button appearing under?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I want the remove button to appear in the right hand side of browse button. Currently what is happening that is remove button is appearing under.

Please see my code below:

[image: Image of remove button appearing under]

```
<div class="filediv col-md-12">
    <!--  <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UploadFile, "Supporting file upload", new { @style = "", @class = "" })
    <p class="form-text text-muted">
        File upload restrictions are as follows:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Do not upload any personal/confidential information</li>
        <li>File size: @Model.GetBytesasText() MB </li>
        <li>Format: @allowedFileTypes  </li>
    </ul>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { @style = "width: 300px;", @class = "form-control", @type = "file", id = "upload" })
    <!--<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />-->
    <div class="col-md-3 removebuttonone">
        <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-danger" />
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UploadFile)
</div>

<div id="Uploadsecfile" class="filediv uploadsecfile col-md-12" style="display:none">
    <!--  <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UploadFile, "", new { @style = "", @class = "" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { @style = "width: 300px;", @class = "form-control", @type = "file", id = "" })
    <!--<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />-->
    <div class="col-md-3 removebuttonone">
        <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-danger" />
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UploadFile)
</div>
```

Comment: Please share working example

Comment: @SantoshKhalse how do i do this?

Comment: @SantoshKhalse I added a image of the buttons appearing above

Comment: have you tried wrapping the controls before the button with a div with class col-md-9 ?

Comment: @Lidaranis yes I have

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 CSS options:

1. Make the **Browse** and **Remove** buttons `display:inline-block`
2. Make for **Remove** button `float:right`. And add `<div style='clear:both'></div>` after.
3. Create a table `<table><tr><td>**Browse button**</td><td>**Remove button**</td></tr></table>`

Hope it will help

Comment: Memedzade are you able to edit the above code please?

Answer (score 0):

You have already given form-control class to text-box. Which will occupy full with of div. so your button will be pushed to next line. you need to divide row into two different section like this

```
<div class="filediv col-md-12">
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-9">
    <!--  <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UploadFile, "Supporting file upload", new { @style = "", @class = "" })
    <p class="form-text text-muted">
        File upload restrictions are as follows:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Do not upload any personal/confidential information</li>
        <li>File size: @Model.GetBytesasText() MB </li>
        <li>Format: @allowedFileTypes  </li>
    </ul>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { @style = "width: 300px;", @class = "form-control", @type = "file", id = "upload" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UploadFile)
</div>

    <div class="col-md-3 removebuttonone">
        <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-danger" />
    </div>
</div>    
</div>
```

Codepen Link : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjVNwz

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code, I can see you are using [BootStrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) at your page. In bootstrap you can use simply a class name for floating right `pull-right`.
Please refer below code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="filediv col-md-6">
                <!--  <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UploadFile, "Supporting file upload", new { @style = "", @class = "" })
                <p class="form-text text-muted">
                    File upload restrictions are as follows:
                </p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Do not upload any personal/confidential information</li>
                    <li>File size: @Model.GetBytesasText() MB </li>
                    <li>Format: @allowedFileTypes  </li>
                </ul>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { @style = "width: 300px;", @class = "form-control", @type = "file", id = "upload" })
                <!--<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />-->
                <div class="col-md-3 removebuttonone">
                    <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-danger" />
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UploadFile)
            </div>
            <!-- Button Div -->
            <div id="Uploadsecfile" class="filediv uploadsecfile col-md-6 pull-right" style="display:none">
                <!--  <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UploadFile, "", new { @style = "", @class = "" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { @style = "width: 300px;", @class = "form-control", @type = "file", id = "" })
                <!--<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />-->
                <div class="col-md-3 removebuttonone">
                    <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-danger" />
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UploadFile)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Thanks